# Não consigo pegar o valor de um elemento filho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou preenchendo uma table da seguinte maneira:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/users",
    data: { q: search, sort: "repositories" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    jQuery.each(msg.items, function(i, users){
        getRepositories(users.repos_url).done(function (result) {
            var repositories = result.length;
            $( 'tbody' ).append('<tr class="user"><td><a class="username">' + users.login + '</a></td><td>' + repositories + '</td>');
        });
    });
});
```

Só que eu preciso pegar o valor dentro do elemento `<a class="username">`, quando o usuário clicar.

O que eu já tentei:

```
$( ".user .username" ).click( function() {
    console.log($( this ).text());  
});
```

E:

```
$( ".user" ).click( function() {
    console.log($( this ).children('a').text());    
});
```

E não aparece simplesmente nada no console, nem um `undefined`. =(

Comment: se vc postasse o botãozinho ou link já ia ser meio caminho...

Comment: Não entendi seu comentário. @MichelSimões

Comment: Poe o html do botão no post man!

Comment: Tente colocar um exemplo do html gerado para a tabela toda, para podermos testar aqui e resolver o problema. o `<a>` não era para ter `href` ? Ou está a dar o `cursor` por css?

Comment: @MichelSimões Já está! Estou criando pelo `append` do jquery!

Comment: @Isac O `<a>` ter href ou não, não interfere na função `click()`.

Comment: foi maus :) olha a resposta se o valor que voce quer é o users.login deve dar, mas cada vez que voce fizer uma inserção de uma linha dinamicamente pelo JS voce deve redeclarar esse .click para que ele se adeque à nova linha

Comment: @Francisco Sim eu sei, era uma pergunta aparte, pois achei estranho não ter e podia não ter reparado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jeitos de se resolver o problema:

1. Fazer associação do eventos *Click* para os elementos ja no *DOM* e para os que forem criados posteriormente.

   ```
   $('table').on('click', 'a.username', function(e){
       console.log($(this).text());
   });
   ```

   #### Veja funcionando

```js
// Define o evento click
$('table').on('click', 'a.username', function(e){
  console.log($(this).text());
});

var search = 'wellmotta';
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/users",
    data: { q: search, sort: "repositories" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    jQuery.each(msg.items, function(i, users){
        getRepositories(users.repos_url).done(function (result) {
          var repositories = result.length;
          $( 'tbody' ).append('<tr class="user"><td><a class="username">' + users.login + '</a></td><td>' + repositories + '</td>');
        });
      
    });
});

var getRepositories = function(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Repositories</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a class="username">usuario_test</a></td>
      <td>55</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

2. Você deve colocar o código abaixo dentro da chamada do método *done* da função *getRepositories*

   ```
   // off: remove a associação do evento click
   // on: faz associação do evento click
   $(".username").off('click').on('click', function() {
       console.log($(this).text());
   });
   ```

#### Veja funcionando

```js
var search = 'wellmotta';
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/search/users",
    data: { q: search, sort: "repositories" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    jQuery.each(msg.items, function(i, users){
        getRepositories(users.repos_url).done(function (result) {
          var repositories = result.length;
          $( 'tbody' ).append('<tr class="user"><td><a class="username">' + users.login + '</a></td><td>' + repositories + '</td>');
    $(".username").off('click').on('click', function() {
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
        });
      
    });
});

var getRepositories = function(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: url
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Repositories</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

### Referências

- [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim champs e diz se deu certo... 
PS: Se voce fizer uma inserção de outra linha após o carregar total da tela, precisa redeclarar essa condição novamente, logo após inserir uma linha, se não só as antigas terão esse comportamento.

```
$(".username" ).click( function() {
        console.log($(this).html());    
});
```

Comment: Como assim redeclarar? Como eu faria isso? Tentei colocar dentro de uma função e chamar quando finalizar o ajax, mas não funcionou.

Comment: por exemplo, cada vez que você chamar o método para adicionar uma linha, ao final voce copia o código, para ele 'aderir' à nova linha também.