# Problemas com click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON('livros.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      console.log(item.name);
      $("#lista").append("<li><a class='livro'>" + item.name + "</a></li>");
    });
  });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>  
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="lista">

    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

O código acima estou listando meu json e setando com o `append` no html, até ai está tudo funcionando, só que agora quero pegar a ação do click em cada tag `a` do html.
e nao estou conseguindo.

script do click que não esta funcionando:

```
$(document).on('click', '.livro', function() {
  console.log("foi");
});
```

Comment: Tente o seguinte código, `jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.livro', function (event) {
    console.log("foi");
});` Se funcionar explico e adiciono na resposta.

Comment: isso também não funcionou

Comment: Veja esse https://jsfiddle.net/3a6p28u5/14/

Comment: @Barbetta dessa maneira funcionou, obrigado não tinha pensado nessa solução.

Comment: Vou jogar na resposta.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Não consigo pegar o valor de um elemento filho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254133/n%c3%a3o-consigo-pegar-o-valor-de-um-elemento-filho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa é criar uma função para isso e já "desenhar" o elemento na tela com essa função, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      console.log(item.name);
      $("#lista").append("<li><a href='#' onclick='minhaFuncao()'>" + item.name + "</a></li>");
    });
  });

  function minhaFuncao() {
    $("#mensagem").html("Deu certo")
  }

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="lista">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="mensagem">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: uma duvida me surgiu se depois eu quiser pegar o nome do elemento que a pessoa clicou eu vou conseguir passar parâmetro pelo onclick mesmo ele estando dentro de um append?

Comment: Claro, se for apenas o nome você pode passar como parâmetro, atualizei o Fiddle com um exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/3a6p28u5/17/, caso seja mais itens, podemos passar o elemento todo no parametro

Comment: certo só que me parece que ele esta com problemas de aspas, no javascript eu não consegui fazer aquele esquema de colocar a "\" pra quebrar as aspas é possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Estranho.. era para funcionar normal, deixa eu ver outra alternativa aqui.., tente assim: `minhaFuncao(\""+item.name+"\")`

Comment: deu certinho obrigado, desculpa pelas perguntas sou novato em javascript

Comment: Imagina, estamos ai para isso ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está funcionando perfeitamente...
Tente verificar se não existem outros *handler's* para a classe `livro`, ou verifique se não há nenhum `preventDefault()` no clique

```js
let dataMock = [ { name: "Harry Potter e as Reliquias da Morte" }, { name: "Fundação Parte II" } ];
$.each(dataMock, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item.name);
    $("#lista").append("<li><a class='livro'>" + item.name + "</a></li>");
});


$(document).on('click', '.livro', function(){
    console.log("foi");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="lista">

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: não achei nada de diferente no meu código, mas aparentemente era pra funcionar e não consigo entender o porque que ele não me retorna o click

Comment: Então coloque seu código inteiro em um JSFiddle e compartilhe o link, para podermos analisar melhor :)

Comment: coloquei meu código completo.

Answer (score 0):

código completo. não consegui colocar no jsfiddle pois não ia dar pra colocar meu arquivo json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
<head>
    <title>json read</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.getJSON('livros.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                console.log(item.name);
                $("#lista").append("<li><a id='livro'>"+item.name+"</a></li>");
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.livro', function(){
            console.log("foi");
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="lista">

        </ul>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

arquivo json, não é o arquivo completo pois é muito grande peguei só uma parte dele

```
[
    {
        "abbrev": "hob", 
        "chapters": [
            [
                "capitulo 1."
            ],
            [
                "capitulo 2."
            ] 
        ],
        "name": "hoobit"
    },

    {
        "abbrev": "hp",
        "chapters": [
        [
            "capitulo 1."
        ],
        [
            "capitulo 2." 
        ]
    ],
        "name": "harry potter"
    } 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui no exemplo que fiz funcionou:

> Apenas troque no seu código **$(document).on('click', '.livro', function()** por **$(".livro").on('click', function()**

```js
var livros = [
    {
        "abbrev": "hob", 
        "chapters": [
            [
                "capitulo 1."
            ],
            [
                "capitulo 2."
            ] 
        ],
        "name": "hoobit"
    },

    {
        "abbrev": "hp",
        "chapters": [
        [
            "capitulo 1."
        ],
        [
            "capitulo 2." 
        ]
    ],
        "name": "harry potter"
    } 
]  
  
  
$.each(livros, function(i, item) {
  $("#lista").append("<li><a class='livro'>"+item.name+"</a></li>");
});

$(".livro").on("click", function() {  // pega o click do <a class="livro">
  console.log("funcionou");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="lista">
  
  </ul>        
</div>
```